# Redirect lldb output to file

Tags: lldb, io-redirection

I'm using lldb inside Xcode, and one of my variables contains a huge chunk of JSON data. Using `po myVar` isn't much helpful to analyse this data, as it will output in the tiny Xcode debug console.

**Is there a way to redirect lldb output to a file ?**

I saw [here](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html) that such a feature seems to be available on gdb as :

```
(gdb) set logging on
(gdb) set logging file /tmp/mem.txt
(gdb) x/512bx 0xbffff3c0
(gdb) set logging off
```

and is "translated" in lldb as :

```
(lldb) memory read --outfile /tmp/mem.txt --count 512 0xbffff3c0
(lldb) me r -o/tmp/mem.txt -c512 0xbffff3c0
(lldb) x/512bx -o/tmp/mem.txt 0xbffff3c0
```

However, the `memory read` command will not help in my case, and apparently, `--outfile` is not available for the `print` command.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a Python script to do so (and much more), as explained here:

[LLDB Python scripting in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232208/lldb-python-scripting-in-xcode)

Create a file named po.py in a directory of your choice (for example "~/.lldb"):

```
import lldb

def print_to_file(debugger, command, result, dict):
  #Change the output file to a path/name of your choice
  f=open("/Users/user/temp.txt","w")
  debugger.SetOutputFileHandle(f,True);
  #Change command to the command you want the output of
  command = "po self"
  debugger.HandleCommand(command)

def __lldb_init_module (debugger, dict):
  debugger.HandleCommand('command script add -f po.print_to_file print_to_file ')
```

Then in lldb write:

```
command script import ~/.lldb/po.py
print_to_file
```

Comment: Improvements here: why not make the command an argument - then you could say “print_to_file po self”? Also, I haven’t checked whether LLDB automagically resets the handles for you, but it would seem good practice to reset the output file handle :) Lastly, you could actually just fetch the SBCommandReturnObject for the ‘inferior command’ (po self in the example) and write it to a file instead of hijacking lldb’s stdout. I would generally be wary of trying to play around with stdin/stdout if at all avoidable.

Comment: Is there a way to redirect *all* debugger output to a file?

I tried the above script without `HandleCommand` line and it didn't work.

Comment: Enrico, could you consider showing an example/answer of your own that improves upon this one? I like the sound of your approach but I don't have enough info to test it.

Comment: For very large structures, the data seems to get truncated to about 61000 lines, 1.4M... Not sure if im missing a cache setting somewhere

Comment: Note that this pipes all further output from *any* command to the file, unless you get the original handle w/ `debugger.GetOutputFileHandle()` and restore it after the handler executes.

Answer (score 4):

I found `session save <filename>` to be a much better, easier option than those listed here. It's not quite the same as you can't use it (to my knowledge selectively) but for generating logs, it's quite handy.

Answer (score 4):

## Redirect lldb command output to file

two method:

- session save
- lldb python script add new command (eg: `write`)

### session save

- syntax: `session save {outputFileFullPath}`

  - Pros: no need extra command, save all session output to file
  - Cons: can not save specific command output to single file
- example:

  - `session save /Users/crifan/dev/tmp/sub_1000A0460.txt`

    - [image: lldb sub_1000A0460.txt]

### lldb script add new command: write

refer: [4iar/lldb-write: Write the output of an lldb command to file](https://github.com/4iar/lldb-write)

steps:

- download code

  - `git clone https://github.com/4iar/lldb-write.git`
- add to lldb init script

  - `vi ~/.lldbinit`
  - add `command script import /{change_to_your_path}/lldb-write/write.py`
- restart lldb
- usage

  - `write /some/path/outputFile.txt {yourOriginLldbCommand}`
- example

  - for `dis -f` is: `write /Users/crifan/dev/tmp/lldb_akd_symbol2575_disassemble.txt dis -f`

    - [image: lldb_akd_symbol2575_disassemble]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight modification incorporating some of the comments from above:

```
def toFile(debugger, command, result, dict):
    f=open("/Users/user/temp.txt","w")
    debugger.SetOutputFileHandle(f,True);
    debugger.HandleCommand(command)  
    f.close()
    debugger.SetOutputFileHandle(sys.stdout, True)
```

This allows the command to be supplied as an argument, and reverts the output file handle to stdout after the command is run.

Comment: Did you try it?  I get: `ValueError: file descriptor cannot be a negative integer (-1)`

Comment: I figured it out.  You have to use `debugger.SetOutputFileHandle(sys.__stdout__, True)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a variable named jsonData (which has a Data type) you can save it to a file with this command:

```
expr jsonData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/tmp/datadump.bin"))
```

Alternatively instead of above command you could dump memory used by this variable to a file as in the example below:

```
(lldb) po jsonData
▿ Optional<Data>
  ▿ some : 32547 bytes
    - count : 32547
    ▿ pointer : 0x00007fe8b69bb410
      - pointerValue : 140637472797712

(lldb) memory read --force --binary --outfile /tmp/datadump.bin --count 32547 0x00007fe8b69bb410
32547 bytes written to '/tmp/datadump.bin'
```