# Write content of variable to file with LLDB

Tags: swift, lldb

I am debugging some JSON in Swift and want to know if there is a way to write the content of a variable to file. Consider a trivial example:

```
let jsonString = "{\"name\": \"John\", \"age\": 21}"
```

How can I write `jsonString` to a local file for more detailed examination when pausing for debug with LLDB?

Comment: you can use userdefault

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/19176672/1187415.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call `write(toFile:atomically:encoding:)`. For example

```
(lldb) call jsonString.write(toFile: "path/to/file", atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
```

You could make this more convenient using lldb's regex aliases. For example if you wanted a `dump` command, to run like this:

```
(lldb) dump jsonString path/to/file
```

Put the following into your `~/.lldbinit` file to use this `dump` alias:

```
command regex dump 's/(.+) (.+)/call %1.write(toFile: "%2", atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)/'
```